# Tkinter Entry box data format

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, serial-port, usb

Getting a set of variables on a tkinter (Python GUI) entry box (on a RPi) in order to ping an ip address, check a usb device's presence(with VID & PID) and to check a com port.
However when the GUI takes in the data, the function runs, but the variables taken from the entry are not executed properly.

i tried converting the input of ip address to string and vid and pid to int, same for com port entries. but the code still won't run.

## scripts to ping IP and to check for usb devices(not the full code):

```
response = os.system("ping -c 1 " + self.ip_address)
```

## pings ip and returns answer according to response

```
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=self.vid, idProduct= self.pid)
```

## checks usb and returns answer according to response

## tkinter settings:

```
entry_IP = Entry(second_frame, bg="white")
entry_IP.grid(row=4,column=1,padx=0,pady=5)
str_IP=entry_IP.get()
```

## main code:

```
RM=classname(str_IP,int_VID,int_PID)
RM.check_IP()
RM.check_USB()
```

i expected the code to run or not, but instead its always telling me the device(s) is not there.
when i run the function alone without a tkinter entry it works just fine !

Comment: `Entry()` is not `input()` - it doesn't wait for your data. If you put `entry_IP.get()` directly after `Entry()` then it is executed at start even before you see window - and it gets empty string from `Entry()`. Better use some `Button()` to run function which will uses `entry_IP.get()`.

Comment: i am trying to use the ip as a variable in my object, eventhough i understand what caused the problem now, i cannot fix it.

Comment: you show only part of code and don't expect better answer. And it doesn't matter if you use variable because it will not update value when you put IP in Entry. You have to call again `str_IP = entry_IP.get()` to get value from `Entry` . If you have `Button` then you should create object when you press it.

Comment: Please show a proper [mcve]. Almost certainly you are either calling the function before the inputs have been initialized, or you are trying to get and use the values of the inputs before the user has a chance to type anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define `str_IP`, the entry contains nothing, and so it will equal to an empty string. You should retrieve the IP directly by passing `RM=class name(entry.get(),...)`

Comment: this is quite helpful because after running a script i found out you're right. its taking an empty string.
However, if i pass RM= classname(entry_IP.get(),...) its still taking it as an empty string...

Comment: You need to call the method only if the entry field is filled, probably by a button or binding a callback.

Comment: It works , i removed the class and called the entry once in the script. however with the usb script the problem remains !

Comment: As the others commented, you will need to post a minimal sample on how you actually call the methods before we can point out what exactly went wrong. But generally in a GUI, you should let the user decide when to fire the callback.